# How to get date as Header in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to get dates as headers that change depending on the current date. Here is an example of what I am trying to do in SQL Server 2005.
    select c.[ar cust edi sef type],
        SUM(case when
            s.[ar sale date] like DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))-7  and s.[ar sale document type] like 'invoice'
            then s.[AR SALE Balance Due]
            else 0 end) as getdate(),

getdate() does not work.  Is there a way I can return a date as the header?

Comment: The usual method for doing this is to add a date field to query and then handle the layout in the application or report logic.  Consider this: if the header is dynamic, how do you plan to refer to it at all in your report or application?  You'd have to determine it dynamically there, too, and hope your logic matches.

Answer (score 0):

Column headers can not be dynamic. You can see this from the fact that usually you don't specify them as string, but like an identifier.

```
SELECT 1 as TestColumn
```

instead of

```
SELECT 1 as 'TestColumn'
```

You could do what you want in the form of a query you execute through `exec`

```
exec('SELECT 1 AS ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean for date header?

[image: Screenshot]

You can do this without pivot, but mostly mssql uses pivot.

Answer (score 0):

This code will list the dates as column headers. Used dynamic PIVOT to obtained the result. First I create a table with dates and a random  text to test the solution. Substitute your table and change the code accordingly.

If you can provide your schema and data the answer will be more applicable and practical.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20110901'
, @EndDate DATE = '20111001'

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) AS [Date]
,'test' AS  [Value]
into #temp_Dates
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
      FROM      sys.columns c
    ) nbrs
WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 


-----------Dynamic PIVOT section to make the date as a column header------------------

DECLARE @SQL  AS VARCHAR(MAX)
, @cols_ AS  vARCHAR(MAX) 
, @Table_Name VARCHAR(20)
SET @Table_Name = '#temp_Dates' 

--Making the column list dynamically 
 SELECT @cols_   = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME(  [T2].[Date]) 
               FROM  #temp_Dates [T2]              
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')          

SET @SQL = ' SELECT
       pivoted.* 
     
      FROM 
      (

      SELECT * 
      
      FROM  '+@Table_Name+'
     
      ) AS [p]
      PIVOT
      (
         MIN([P].[Value]) 
         FOR  [P].[Date]  IN (' + @cols_ + ')         
      ) AS pivoted;        

   ';

  PRINT( @SQL)
  EXEC (@SQL)


  DROP TABLE #temp_Dates
```

RESULT: [image: PIVOTED TABLE RESULT]